# Update Scope on jquery click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[image]I have a directive, that is listening on click on body, and it updates a property in an object. If I log the variable test of the object, it has the true value always, but if I log myObj, I see that test is updated. What to do?????

```
scope.myObj.test = false;
angular.element('body').unbind().click(function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
       console.log(scope.myObj, 'here the test prop is true');
       console.log(scope.myObj.test, 'here the test prop is still false');
       if (!scope.myObj.test)
           scope.myObj.test = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: What? I dont understand

Comment: Try and use the variable and see what happens...

Comment: scope.myobj returns true cause you have declared it and the other one returns false because you've declared it as false

Comment: scope.myobj returns true - no this is an object, test is a property of this object, and test is true

Comment: variables gets updated, but my directive uses ng-show="myObj.test". I dont want to use jquery for showing/hiding. what am I doing here wrong?

Comment: img with the log, the active property is in question. whyyyyyyyy?

Answer (score 0):

```
   console.log(scope.myObj, 'here the test prop is true');
   console.log(scope.myObj.test, 'here the test prop is still false');
```

This is not possible - the lines are consecutive and nothing changes between them.

If you are using the chrome developer tools, note that if you output an object to the console, it is evaluated when you expand it.

Instead, try this:

```
   console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.myObj));
   console.log(scope.myObj.test);
```